# Parallel logging of serial port

Tags: python, serial-port, python-multiprocessing, pyserial

I have a program, my_prog, that communicates with some HW and is generating output through a UART port.
The HW supports two types of communication, ethernet and UART. I am using the ethernet platform to send control commands to the HW using Python's pexpect, and to verify that those commands was received by the HW, but I also need to log the UART ports because they conatin more data.
I want to log the UART ports while my_prog is running, and save the log to a file.
The logger needs to work in parallel to my_prog so it can capture all the output while my_prog is running.
My code goes something like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import pexpect


class my_prog_class:
    def __init__():
        self.uart_logger = uart_logger_drv()
        self.process = pexpect.spawn('hw_activation_command')

def my_prog(self,queue):
    # Send some control commands using pexpect and get response using ethernet comm...
    queue.put("stop_logging")

class uart_logger:
    def __init__(self):
        self.core_port = serial.Serial(
        port='/dev/ttyUSB0',
        baudrate=115200,
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
        timeout=0)

    def logger_control(self,queue):
        """
        Description: Log my_prog
        """
        core_1_file_path = 'core_1_log.txt'
        with open(core_1_file_path, 'a') as core_log:
            while(queue.empty()==True):
                line1 = self.core_port.readline().decode( "utf-8" )    
                core_log.write(re.sub(r'\t', '',line1))

test_instance = my_prog_class()
queue = Queue()
test_process = Process(target=test_instance.my_prog,args=(queue,),name='test_process')
uart_logger_process =  Process(target=test_instance.uart_logger.logger_control,args= 
(queue,),name='uart_logger_process')
test_process.start()
uart_logger_process.start()
test_process.join()
```

My problem is that some of the expected data (I compared to a log file that was generated by manual activation of the HW) is missing, the logger is not printing anything for a small period of time every 3 seconds or so.
Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Can You try to run Your logger without running main eth process? Just to see if it's only problem of logging loop or this issue is somehow related to communication with both interfaces at once.